# Daily stock data request

Tags: data-request

I want to get past daily charts for stocks I'm looking at but I can't seem to find any websites that display this real-time data. The daily high, low, close, and open isn’t enough information to suit my needs.

Comment: [Qd Investments Co](https://qdinvestments.co/historical/) might be a good fit for you. It has historical fundamental data for a lot of stocks. Also has a trial which is nice. They look pretty new to the market so are probably quite helpful in terms of if there are missing features helping you out. What type of data are you needing?

Answer (score 2):

[Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/) is a site thats pretty useful for getting historical stock data.

You can get some pretty big datasets (i.e. you can get daily stock market data for [Microsoft](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?period1=511074000&period2=1531972800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d) going back to 1989 till now).

Hope this helps.

Comment: AFAIK, Yahoo stopped providing that feed a while back. I think it was sometimes this year..

Comment: Have you tried calling?  Maybe they have free options for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more granular that daily information then you may need to subscribe/use a third party api.

I believe Quantopian, interactive brokers, and  (maybe, I haven’t used it) robinhood can access data like this, but you’ll need an account for all (quantopian is free, but limited to their notebook platform).

Answer (score 0):

use the platform " Thinkorswim ". You will find exactly what you are looking for, and even more. Totally free.